# How to make Callback run after Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to connect to database through SEQUELIZE first, and afterwords through MYSQL package. One returns a Promise, another is built on callbacks and therefore the second one executes first. What is the way to make a callback
 "wait" ?

```
const db = require('./config/db');
const dbManual = require('./config/dbManual');

(async () => {
    try {
        await db.authenticate();
        console.log('database connected with "sequelize" package');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();

(() => {
    dbManual.connect(err =>
        err
            ? console.error(err)
            : console.log('database connected with "mysql" package')
    );
})();
```

Comment: its better to call your db. authenticate inside your second method call! did you try that?

Comment: I'm just trying to wrap my head around promises vs callbacks, that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the following code.

```
const db = require('./config/db');
const dbManual = require('./config/dbManual');

(async () => {
    try {
        await db.authenticate();
        console.log('database connected with "sequelize" package');
        dbManual.connect(err =>
                  err
                      ? console.error(err)
                      : console.log('database connected with "mysql" package')
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const db = require('./config/db');
const dbManual = require('./config/dbManual');

const authenticate = (async () => {
    try {
        await db.authenticate();
        console.log('database connected with "sequelize" package');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});

(async () => {
    await authenticate();
    dbManual.connect(err =>
        err
            ? console.error(err)
            : console.log('database connected with "mysql" package')
    );
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const connect_seq = async () => {
    try {
        await db.authenticate();
        console.log('database connected with "sequelize" package');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

const connect_mysql = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        dbManual.connect(err =>
            err
                ? reject(err)
                : resolve(console.log('database connected with "mysql" package'))
        );
    })

};

(async ()=> {
    await connect_seq();
    await connect_mysql();
 })()
```

Comment: this code won't work because connect_sql and connect_mysql functions aren't hoisted i.e. they can't be called before they're declared

Answer (score 1):

Try using then()

you can read more in here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

```
const db = require('./config/db');
const dbManual = require('./config/dbManual');

const connect = () => {
        return db.authenticate().then((response) =>{
          console.log('database connected with "sequelize" package');
          dbManual.connect(err =>
            err ? console.error(err) : console.log('database connected with "mysql" package')
        );
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            process.exit(1);
        })
}
```

Tho connect function will return a promise that you can await for